# QCOMPARE of two floating-point infinity-values

Tags: c++, qt, floating-point, infinity, qtestlib

```
QCOMPARE(
    std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(),
    std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
```

fails with:

```
Compared doubles are not the same (fuzzy compare)
       Actual   (std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()): inf
       Expected (std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()): inf
       Loc: [...]
```

#### Question

Why does this fail? Is there a good work-around (other than using `QVERIFY` instead)?

**UPDATE:**

I mean a work-around from the perspective of a test-writer. It is desirable to provide a proper diagnostic with the actual value which is not infinity. Instead of

```
QCOMPARE(val, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
```

one could

```
QVERIFY(val == std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()))
```

but the value of `val` is not shown in the generated diagnostic message if the check fails. Looks like a major oversight from developers.
So do I have to roll-out my own macro with exact comparison similar to `QCOMPARE`?  Any recommendations here?

Also, it is clear that `qFuzzyCompare` does not support some corner-cases. But I hoped for a more in-depth explanation of why this is the case.

Comment: Anything called "fuzzy compare" is inherently suspect. Apparently it's doing something other than comparing for exact equality.

Comment: This smells like a good feature request to submit on [Qt's bugtracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/).

Comment: As a workaround, of course, you can c&p what QCOMPARE does for floating points (see [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/testlib/qtestcase.cpp.html#_ZN5QTest8qCompareERKdS1_PKcS3_S3_i)), but turn that `qFuzzyCompare` in a more thorough check (e.g. via `fpclassify`). Which, by the way, opens the question on what you want to do with denormal numbers.

Answer (score 3):

QCOMPARE in the case of comparing floats and doubles, qFuzzyCompare() is used. (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#QCOMPARE)

Based on (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qFuzzyCompare), Qt documentation it self says that comparing infinity will not work. - **"Note that comparing values where either p1 or p2 is 0.0 will not work, nor does comparing values where one of the values is NaN or infinity"**.

My guess, why infinity can not be compared is, there is no specific value for infinity,I mean "***infinity-1***" is also infinity. Then obviously comparison is a question here.

***Workaround:***

If you want to compare infinity, Then use below function and compare the return Boolean values.

```
bool qIsInf(double d)
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qIsInf

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I hoped for a little different angle in the answer. Please see the update in my question.

Comment: Agree with your update. At least they should have printed the "val".

Comment: If you write your own macro, you may not be able address all the features of Qt's QCOMPARE

Answer (score 2):

As there is still no working example, I post my own macro here:

```
#include <qtestcase.h>

#define COMPARE_DBL(actual, expected, epsilon) \
do {\
    if (!QTest::compare_helper((qAbs(actual - expected) <= epsilon), \
                               QString{"Compared values are not the same in respect to epsilon %1"} \
                                    .arg(epsilon).toLocal8Bit().constData(), \
                               QTest::toString(actual), \
                               QTest::toString(expected), \
                               #actual, #expected, __FILE__, __LINE__)) \
        return;\
} while (false)
```

It prints out an error message formatted by Qt and correctly interrupts the test case.

Comment: This does not handle exact comparison for the edge cases +-infinity, +-NaN and +-0, but is very close.

Comment: For a relative comparison, multiply `epsilon` by `(1+qAbs(actual)+qAbs(expected))`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a custom marco. It mimics `QCOMPARE` output and does not stick out.

Here it is (feel free to re-use):

```
inline void isEqualsExactly(
    const double actual,
    const double expected,
    const std::string& actualName,
    const std::string& expectedName)
{
    if(expected == actual)
        return;
    std::stringstream warn;
    const size_t w = std::max(actualName.length(), expectedName.length());
    warn << "Compared values are not the same" << std::endl;
    warn << "   Actual   " << std::setw(w) << std::setfill(' ') << actualName;
    warn << ": " << std::to_string(actual) << std::endl;
    warn << "   Expected " << std::setw(w) << std::setfill(' ') << expectedName;
    warn << ": " << std::to_string(expected);
    QFAIL(warn.str().c_str());
}

#define QCOMPARE_EXACT(actual, expected) \
    isEqualsExactly(actual, expected, #actual, #expected);
```

---

Usage:

```
const double val = 0;
const double infinity = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
QCOMPARE_EXACT(val, infinity);
```

Output:

```
FAIL!  : TestName Compared values are not the same
   Actual        val: 0.000000
   Expected infinity: inf  
   Loc: [link to location in file]
```

---

**P.S.** I agree, this should be a feature request. The situation is ridiculous. If I will make one, I will update the post.

Comment: You cannot use QFAIL within a function because it shall interrupt the test with a return call. In your implementation the test will continue in case of a fail.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the approach by @thomas-klier, the following macro works for me:

```cpp
#define COMPARE_DBL(actual, expected, epsilon) \
do {\
    if (!QTest::compare_helper( ((qAbs(actual - expected) <= epsilon) || (actual == expected)), \
        QString{"Compared values are not the same in respect to epsilon %1"} \
             .arg(epsilon).toLocal8Bit().constData(), \
        QTest::toString(actual), \
        QTest::toString(expected), \
        #actual, #expected, __FILE__, __LINE__)) \
        return;\
} while (false)
```